# Different mechanism of HttpClient in Blazor server side and Web assembly

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I want to get data from ASP.net Core API with HttpClient Factory.
I use Microsoft.Extensions.Http package like this :

```
// Register service in IOC containter 
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IProductService, ProductService>(option =>
                {
                    option.BaseAddress = new Uri(""/*Base url*/);
                });

// Use in service 
var stream = await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync("");
```

When I use code in Blazor server side and works correctly. But when I use code in Blazor wasm throw Exception

> Access to fetch at 'http client factory base url' from origin 'blazor wasm app url' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

No change in ASP.net core API and different results.
I use .net core 3.1 in all apps
Thanks

Comment: Please read up on CORS. https://darnton.co.nz/2020/07/13/cors-proxy-for-client-side-blazor/

Comment: It seems that you need to enable CORS in Blazor wasm, check [Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors) and [ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly Cross-origin resource sharing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors).

Comment: The mechanism isn't different - you're making the calls from different *machines*. When you use Blazor Server, the HTTP request is made from the server. When you use Blazor WASM, the HTTP call is made from the *browser*. That's no different than making a `fetch` call from the browser in Javascript. The *browser* prevents Javascript pages from calling unrelated URLs as a way to prevent script injection.

Comment: @brian-parker link is talking about pre-flight pulse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I activate CORS in my API Like this

```
// In ConfigureServices method
    options.AddPolicy("OpenCors", builder =>
                {
                    builder
                          .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                      ;
});

// In Configure method
app.UseCors("OpenCors");
```